# Including client-side scripts in head in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-4.0

Hey guys. I don't do HTML or Javascript, I prefer to work in C#, but one of the JS guys tells me that he needs a script included within the head tag. The page in question is a content page of a master page. I can't seem to make this work. I tried adding the script by a programmatic reference `this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude`, but it came out in the `<body>` tag. I tried adding a ScriptManager and a ScriptReference in the contentplaceholder inside the `<head>` tag of the master page, but this didn't work either. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a client side reference to the script in.

```
<head> <script lang="Javascript" src="./scripts/yourscript.js"></script>
```

Or, if it needs to be inline, include the actual script right there in the master page.

Comment: The purpose of doing it in the content page is so that it doesn't get included in the master page. Surely you can't just go declaring `<head>` twice?

Comment: This was the right answer. Turns out that you can just spew HTML inside the Content tag.

Comment: I misread the question and thought you wanted it in the master page. Sorry about that. I guess you could do it in the master page but with a conditional that it only appeared on this one page.